# In 'The hat is red', how do we know that 'is red' is a constituent?

Tags: constituents

As far as I understand, in the sentence

[1] *The hat i̲s̲ ̲r̲e̲d̲.*

the underlined part, *is red*, is a syntactical [constituent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) ('a group of words that functions as a single unit within a hierarchical structure'). I'm interested in the point of view of phrase structure grammar.

So far, I can justify the claim that it is a constituent only by appeal to authority. For example, on p. 50 of [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), it is stated that in the sentence *he is ill*, the *is ill* is a verb phrase (VP) and a constituent, as evident from the following tree diagram:

[image: constituent structure of 'he is ill' from CGEL, p. 50]

And surely, whatever reasons CGEL has to favor its analysis of *he is ill*, completely analogous arguments will show that *is red* is a VP and a constituent in [1].

The trouble is, it is not entirely clear what those arguments *are*.

The authority of grammars and textbooks must ultimately come from linguistic evidence, which, in turn, is collected one specific example at a time. In particular, I was hoping that it may be possible to demonstrate that *is red* is a constituent by applying some sort of constituenthood test. An example of such a test: a pro-form substitution test. A word sequence 'passes that test' (and is thus a constituent) if we can find a sentence, acceptable to most native speakers, in which that word sequence is substituted by a [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form).

The pro-form substitution test can be used to show that large classes of verb phrases are constituents. For example, consider

[2] *John h̲i̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲a̲l̲l̲.*

We suspect that *hit the ball* is a constituent. To demonstrate this, note that the following is a grammatically acceptable sentence:

[3] *Jack h̲i̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲a̲l̲l̲ and John d̲i̲d̲, too.*

We see that in the second conjunct, *hit the ball* is substituted for by the pro-form *did*, and is therefore a constituent.

However, I haven't been able to come up with a definitive constituenthood test that *is red* clearly passes. As far as I understand, testing for constituenthood of verb phrases (VPs) is indeed trickier than in the case of other kinds of phrases. Apart from pro-form substitution, there are other kinds of reliable tests that can often be used for determining whether some word sequence is a VP. One, for example, is (what McCawley calls) [V'-deletion](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=when+is+something+not+a+constituent&source=bl&ots=uOkE8M4CTg&sig=Ufrwji6PbNuTsvQ_zP03YpYu-Lc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAlcvo-9nSAhVE54MKHdr0Ax0Q6AEIUTAR#v=onepage&q=when%20is%20something%20not%20a%20constituent&f=false). Unfortunately, thus far, I am unable to find a way to use that (or any other) reliable test in the case of *is red*.

True, *is red* can be coordinated with something that is definitely a VP, as in

[4] *The hat is red and weighs 151 g*.

However, this is not enough to show that *is red* is a VP and a constituent, because (as I'm told in many sources, [including the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#Coordination)) coordination is not a reliable test for constituenthood.

Could someone provide a reliable, clear test of constituenthood that *is red* passes? Or is the argument for its constituenthood more indirect? If the latter, could you provide an outline of the argument? (If possible, I'd like something more concrete than this sentence, found in CGEL (p. 21): 'The full support for a decision in grammatical description consists of confirmation from hundreds of mutually supportive pieces of evidence of many kinds'.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57568/discussion-on-question-by-linguisticturn-in-the-hat-is-red-how-do-we-know-tha).

Comment: I think  you are mixing apples and oranges. /The hat is red/, regardless of whether you see it as a syntactical constituent or  VP , and /John hit the ball/ are are not the same class of utterance at all. I am surprised that none of the luminaries around  here has pointed that out. Ergo, you get an aporia. If you are going to use a pro-form, the pro-form has to be in the same class (or category) of utterance.

Comment: @Lambie I am not entirely sure what you mean, precisely, by 'same class/category of utterance'... but if by that you mean that one is a copular clause, while the other is not, then I definitely agree. Moreover, one symptom of their difference is that it is easy to use the pro-form substitution test for one, but it seems impossible for the other. The only reason I brought up _John hit the ball_ was to illustrate what a successful application of a constituenthood test looks like.

Comment: @Lambie Now, the proximate cause of failure of pro-form substitution in the case of copulas is that the verb _be_ lacks '_do_-support'. Maybe you wish to say that underlying this is the difference in 'class of utterance'... but, to be sure, I'd need to understand better what you mean by 'class/category of utterance'.

Comment: I mean that in the English language, one utterance is copular and the other is transitive. That is apples and oranges. For me, copular verbs are not the hat /is red/. The /is/ is a quasi-operator. The hat/is/red. The /is/ links hat and red. Whereas: in /John hit the ball/, one has: John/hit the ball/ or /John hit/ the ball. /The door/is/open cannot be compared to: The door/is opened/. The two types of utterance are top-level (top of the tree) utterances and fundamentally different.

Comment: @Lambie I _think_ I understand what you are saying, but your third sentence confuses me: 'For me, copular verbs are not the hat /is red/. '

Comment: That's right: "The hat/is/red" is not: "The hat/is red". You are putting the slash in front of the is. I would surround the is by slashes. A copular joins one thing with another (state, condition, etc.). In that sense the verb be is a quasi-operator.

Comment: @Lambie OK. First, we agree on a lot: we agree that [1] _the hat is red_ is a copular clause, while [2] _John hit the ball_ is not, and that is a significant difference indeed. We also agree that [2] has two top-level constituents: the NP _John_ and the VP _hit the ball_. Now, in the case of [1], you favor the analysis where it has not two, but three immediate constituents, i.e. [The hat] [is] [red]. Several points:

Comment: @Lambie 1. the fact that [1] and [2] differ with respect to whether they are copular does not, in and of itself, immediately imply that [1] _cannot_ have a VP as an immediate constituent just because [2] _does_ have one. The assertion that [1] has three rather than two immediate constituents requires an argument just as much as the opposite claim that it has two rather than three. In particular, it is perfectly possible that [1] has a VP constituent for one set of reasons, whereas [2] has a VP constituent for a different set of reasons, but that in the end, both have a VP constituent.

Comment: @Lambie 2. In other words: just because the constituenthood of _is red_ cannot be established in the same way as it can in the case of _hit the ball_ doesn't mean that the constituenthood of _is red_ can't be established in some other way. For example, _is red_ can be coordinated, and this is at least some evidence that it is a constituent. In fact, in my own answer to my own question, I argue that this latter observation can be turned into a solid argument.

Comment: @Lambie 3. Note that when you say that [1] has three rather than two immediate constituents, you are disagreeing with basically every English grammar written in the past 100 years at least, and also with grammars of other languages that retain copulas as opposed to omit them (like even some dialects of English do). It's of course OK to disagree with authorities, but, agree or not, one should provide an _argument_ for the position one is taking---and if one is going against tradition, that need is, if anything, even stronger.

Answer (score 1):

I did mention in my question that there is *one* piece of evidence that *is red* is a constituent: it can be coordinated with something that is definitely a VP, as in

[1] *The hat is red and weighs 151 g.*

I also said that this is weak evidence because it is known that one can sometimes coordinate non-constituents.

However, I now think that if one supplements [1] with additional considerations, as I will do below, this will turn it into a much stronger argument---possibly strong enough to be acceptable as the answer to my question.

Please tell me what you think by upvoting (or downvoting) and by commenting. (But if you do downvote, please explain why.) Whether I accept this answer or not will depend on the feedback I receive (unless, of course, a clearly better answer appears in the meantime).

The required additional considerations are outlined in [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468)  (pp. 1348-1350): 'Coordination as evidence for a VP constituent'. Basically, we will ask 'what else could *is red* in [1] be but a constituent?', consider all known alternatives in turn, and conclude that the analysis where *is red* is a constituent is better than all the alternatives.

**The principle**

What CGEL says is that we have the following principle:

> [35] In general, if a sequence X can be coordinated with a sequence Y
>   to form a coordination X *and* Y, then X and Y are constituents,

but adds:

> Coordination clearly does not provide a simple and absolute criterion
>   for constituent structure: the qualification 'in general' in [35] is
>   indispensable. It nevertheless remains a useful criterion: if a
>   sequence X can be coordinated, then the simplest account will be one
>   where it is a constituent entering into basic coordination, and we
>   will adopt some other, more complex, analysis only if there are
>   independent reasons for doing so.

Thus we will say that X is a constituent if that is the **simplest** analysis that accounts for all facts---and that is usually the most we can ask for in any analysis, linguistic or otherwise, for there is no upper bound on how complex an analysis one can invent.

CGEL's discussion uses the sentence *Sue found the key* as its test case. I will reproduce what they say about it, and then, at each stage, discuss how what was said relates to *The hat is red.*

> How does coordination support the analysis of a clause like *Sue found
>   the key* into two immediate constituents, as in [36i], rather than
>   three,  as in [ii]?
>
> [36] i *Sue | found the key.* 
>                         [NP
>   + VP: the VP analysis] 
>          ii *Sue | found |
>   the key*     [NP + V + NP: the 'no VP' analysis]
>
> **Principle [35] supports the VP analysis**
>
> The sequence *found the key* can be readily coordinated:
>
> [37] *Sue found the key and unlocked the door.*
>
> Only analysis [36i] is therefore consistent with principle [35]; other
>   things being equal, it is  to be preferred over [36ii] because it
>   allows us to subsume [37] under basic coordination, so that it
>   requires no special treatment. Principle [35], however, is qualified,
>   not absolute, so we need to consider the matter further.

So far, word for word, the discussion applies to *The hat is red*: does the sentence have two immediate constituents (*The hat* | *is red*) or three (*The hat* | *is* | *red*)?

**The additional considerations**

> **VP-coordination vs clause-coordination with ellipsis of the subject**
>
> An alternative treatment of the coordination here, one that is
>   consistent with [36ii], is to say that the coordinates are clauses,
>   the second having ellipsis of the subject. The first coordinate will
>   then be not *found the key* but *Sue found the key*, and the second
>   will be    ̲ ̲    *unlocked the door*. This
>   accounts for the equivalence between [37] and *Sue found the key and
>   she unlocked  the door*. But we saw in §1.3.1 that there are many
>   cases where no such equivalence obtains, as in:
>
> [38] i *No one treats me like that and gets away with it.*  
>                
>         [VP-coordination]
>          ii *No one treats me like that
>   and no one gets away with it.*   [clause-coordination]
>
> An elliptical clause analysis doesn't provide a satisfactory account
>   of coordination like [38i].

In our case, the challenge to explain why *The hat is red and weighs 151 g* must be an instance where we coordinate the VP *is red* with the VP *weighs 151 g* (so-called 'VP-coordination'). Why couldn't it instead be an instance of 'clause coordination', where we have an ellipted subject in the second coordinate? In other words, why can't we say that *The hat is red and weighs 151 g* is completely equivalent to *The hat is red and  [it]/[the hat] weighs 151 g*? It seems that either reading would work equally well.

CGEL points out that in some settings, the two readings do not work equally well. So consider *No hat is red and weighs 2 lbs*, and note that it does *not* mean the same thing as *No hat is red and no hat weighs 2 lbs* . The former only says that there are no hats that are *both* red *and* weigh 2 lbs, whereas the latter says that there are no red hats, whatever their weight, and also that there are no hats that weigh 2 lbs, whatever their color. We conclude that  *The hat is red and weighs 151 g* is better analyzed as a VP-coordination than as a clausal coordination.

> **Basic vs right nonce-constituent coordination**
>
> Another alternative consistent with [36ii] would be to say that the
>   underlined sequences in [37] are merely nonce-constituents,
>   constituents in the coordination but not elsewhere. This is to treat
>   [37] like our earlier example:
>
> [39] *I gave $̲1̲0̲ ̲t̲o̲
>   ̲K̲i̲m̲ and $̲5̲
>   ̲t̲o̲ ̲P̲a̲t̲.* (=[i6ii])
>
> There are, however, two important differences between [37] and [39].
>   In the first place, the nonce-constituents in [39] have to be parallel
>   in structure (as noted in §4.3), whereas those in [37] do not -
>   compare, for example, *Sue found the key and departed.* Secondly, the
>   reason why *$10 to Kim* is not a normal constituent is that there is
>   no direct syntactic relation between the parts, *$10* and *to Kim*:
>   they are, rather, separately dependents (complements) of *give*.
>   *Found the key* in [37] is quite different: here there is a syntactic relation between the parts, *found* being head and *the key*
>   dependent. The nonce-constituent analysis is a more complex type of
>   construction than basic coordination, applying under restricted
>   conditions  (the requirement of parallelism) and justified by strong
>   independent arguments against recognising the coordinates as normal
>   constituents: in the case of [37] we have no reason to prefer the more
>   complex analysis to the one that follows the general principle given
>   in [35].

In our case, we also lack any requirement of parallelism  (e.g. *The hat is red and reeks*), and we also have that there is a syntactic relation between *is* and *red*, namely *is* is the copula and *red* a predicative complement of it. Thus, like CGEL, we have no reason to prefer the more complex nonce-constituent analysis to the one that follows the general principle given in [35].

Finally,

> **Basic vs delayed right constituent coordination**
>
> The relevance of [37] to constituent structure might be challenged on
>   the grounds that it is also possible for coordination to group *found*
>   with *Sue*:
>
> [40] *M̲a̲x̲ ̲l̲o̲s̲t̲
>   but S̲u̲e̲
>   ̲f̲o̲u̲n̲d̲ the key.*
>
> If coordination can group *found* with either *the key* or *Sue*, the
>   argument would go, then it can't provide evidence for a constituent
>   grouping of *found* with just one of them, *the key*. But such an
>   argument fails to recognise that there is a major difference between
>   the coordination of [37] and that of [40]. The latter represents a
>   much less usual type of coordination than [37], and this instance of
>   it is indeed of somewhat marginal acceptability because of the low
>   weight of *the key*; acceptability is increased by expanding to *the
>   key to the safe* but greatly diminished by reducing to *it*. Example
>   [40] would characteristically have special prosody, with a clear break
>   before *the key*. [These properties do not hold for all cases of
>   delayed right constituent coordination, but even when they do not
>   there will be independent evidence for treating the coordination as
>   non-basic. Take, for example, [24iii], *He was accused but found not
>   guilty of stalking a woman for seven years*: it is evident that in the
>   non-coordinative *He was found not guilty of stalking a woman for
>   seven years* the *of* phrase is a complement of *guilty*, not *find
>   not guilty*, because it regularly occurs with *guilty* quite
>   independently of the presence of *find*, as in *He was/seemed guilty
>   of treason.*] But [37], by contrast, has no such limitations or
>   special prosody, and can be taken to represent the most elementary
>   type of coordination: as such, it does provide valid evidence in
>   support of the VP analysis.

Again, what CGEL says of its example, we may say of ours. Consider the following instances of 'delayed right constituent coordination' (CGEL's preferred term for what everyone else calls [right node raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising)):

[2] a. *The hat is but the scarf is not red.* 
       b. *The scarf only seems but the hat is red.*

As in CGEL's example [40], [2a] and [2b] are of marginal acceptability, which increases if the 'weight' of the 'extracted element' is increased:

[3] a. *The hat is but the scarf is not a family heirloom left to me by my grandpa.*
       b.  *The scarf only seems but the hat is well over 100 years old.*

Also, when [2a] and [2b] are pronounced, there will characteristically be a prosodic break before *red*.

In contrast, there are no special limitations on the 'weight' of what can be coordinated with *is red* at a given level of acceptibility: on one extreme we may coordinate with a single word, *The hat is red and reeks*, on the other with a much longer phrase, *The hat is red and makes me think of my childhood summers which I spent with my grandpa*, and both are equally acceptable. Also, there is no special prosodic break in any of these.

**Conclusion**

We have contrasted the analysis of

[1] *The hat is red and weighs 151 g.*

(and similar sentences) in which *is red* is a constituent to three possible alternatives: 1. one where [1] coordinates clauses and the second clause has subject ellipsis; 2. one where *is red* and *weighs 151 g* are nonce constituents; and 3. one where *is* is argued to be just as easily grouped with *the hat* as it is with *red*. We found that in all three cases, the analysis where *is red* is a constituent is simpler, more plausible, or both. This gives us solid evidence that *is red* is therefore indeed a constituent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very poor piece of evidence I can think of. Please downvote it if you think it's too weak to be useful; I'd also appreciate any comments if you have specific criticisms.

Consider the title of the book by Stephen Colbert, *[I Am America (And So Can You!)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446582182)*. This has been discussed earlier on this site ([Please explain "I Am America (And So Can You!)"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/please-explain-i-am-america-and-so-can-you)) and on Linguistics SE ([Why exactly is *“I Am America (And So Can You!)” ungrammatical?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/why-exactly-is-i-am-america-and-so-can-you-ungrammatical))

Obviously, this title is ungrammatical. But I see no reason to suppose the ungrammaticality is related to the constituent structure of "am America." And as long as it is ungrammatical for unrelated reasons, it may be legitimate to use this title (which was, after all, created by an English speaker, and which is fairly understandable despite being ungrammatical) as evidence for the constituency of "be X" (although in this case "X" is not obviously an adjective, as in "be red").

And we see that in  the title, the auxiliary "can" seems to precede an elided "be America", which I think is an example of "V'-deletion" indicating that "be America" is a constituent.

(Actually, is there some reason why "The hat will be red, and so will the boots" or ""The hat will be red, and the boots will too" are not examples of "V'-deletion"? Both of these sentences seem grammatical to me. I'm not sure I've understood the idea correctly.)

Comment: This is such a creative answer that I wouldn't dream of downvoting it! As far as V'-deletion,my impression at the moment is that this terminology is special to McCawley, and that most sources (e.g. [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Syntax-Generative-Introduction-Andrew-Carnie/dp/1405133848/), p. 154) would say his examples are replacement/substitution instead, since the word _do_ makes an appearance. Without a _do_, it is just ellipsis, and ellipted material is often _not_ a constituent (although in e.g. stripping the _retained_ material apparently must be). As far as Colbert...

Comment: @linguisticturn: Oh, I think I have trouble understanding how we know it is replacement rather than ellipsis. Couldn't "does" be analyzed as an elliptical version of "does play poker"?

Comment: Colbert: I suppose that the argument is that the sentence is understandable precisely because _so_ is clearly, though ungrammatically, intended to have _am America_ as its antecedent. However, even if we accept that ungrammatical sentences may sometimes be used to figure out constituent structure, it is actually not clear that _so_ in _so can you_ functions as a pro-form. CGEL, for example, analyzes it instead as a connective adjunct indicating a likeness between a clause that preceded it and an ellipted clause (p. 1539, '(b) Other cases of initial _so_ with subject-auxiliary inversion').

Comment: As far as pro-form substitution vs ellipsis: as best as I can tell, normally in ellipsis, the restoration of ellipted material results in a sentence that is perhaps verbose, but whose meaning is the same as the original. Consider e.g. gapping: [1] _John can play the guitar, and Mary the violin_; [2] _John can play the guitar, and Mary can play the violin._ These two have _exactly_ the same meaning.

Comment: But now consider [3] _John hit the ball, and Kim did, too_ and [4] _John hit the ball, and Kim did hit the ball, too._ I would say they are _not_ completely equivalent in meaning: [4] places a special emphasis on Kim hitting the ball, which is not present in [3]. Thus [3] is better analyzed as an instance of replacement than of ellipsis.

Answer (score -2):

To be as simple as possible, the definition of the word 'constituent' that applies to the title is "a part of a whole" or "a component part of something."

Therefore, simply, the hat is something whole that *is red*, making the [is red] in the title "The Hat is Red" a constituent.

Red is the color part of the hat.

Comment: This is not the sense of "constituent" that is being used in the question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics), the Wikipedia article that was linked to in the original post.

Comment: Besides which, color may be an aspect of something but it is not a separate part.